# Quick way to find that object was updated

Tags: c#, .net

I do deserialize object from database on application start, then during application life time user can update object, and at the end object are serialized back into db as xml string. Is there any way to find out that object was updated other than comparing initial and final string.

I know that is possible to use:

1. [String.GetHashCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.gethashcode.aspx) Method, but as noted that "Different strings can return the same hash code".
2. MD5 hash as done in [How to compute and compare hash values by using Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307020). Although I don't know if different strings can return same MD5 hash.

I know that my xml always will be less than 100KB.

Comment: No hash code can ever be unique, unless it's longer than all of the input strings.

Comment: If you're going the hash code route, you could do something similar to what the .Net framework does to speed up equality comparison: Check the object's `GetHashCode` result.  If they're equal, check `Equals`.  If they're still equal, then consider them unchanged.  This is easy to implement, though not the fastest possible.  When you're done with this, profile and see if you actually need a faster method.  The serialization and wire transfer might be much slower than the equality comparisons, so you might be trying to optimize something that isn't your bottleneck.

Comment: If it turns out you need a faster method, you could look into the answer Sam is suggesting (manual change tracking).  Also, the .Net Entity Framework has this sort of change tracking built in.  You could look into using it instead of your custom data access code.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham#1: Comparing string hashcodes is actually _slower_ than comparing them directly, unless you can pre-compute the hashcodes for multiple comparisons.  They both involve iterating over characters.

Comment: @SLaks: Yes, true.  If the OP is going to compare the final strings, he should just go with `Equals` (in this scenario), rather than bothering with any hashing.  But I meant to get the hash code(s) of the object tree rather than the serialized representation.  I guess I didn't make that clear :)  Also, EF doesn't directly support to/from XML serialization, so maybe that solution wouldn't help the OP, unless they can get rid of the whole XML thing to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement `IPropertyChanged`, and track if the object is dirty or not.

Comment: Or at least a private property that the other property setters can tweak when the object is updated.  That gives you the flexibility of deciding whether an update that doesn't alter the value of a property is significant in your application.

Comment: I guess there are no other answers